# Spark Program running very slow on cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, spark-submit

I am trying to run my **PySpark** in Cluster with 2 nodes and 1 master (all have 16 Gb RAM). I have run my spark with below command.

> spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster  --name "Pyspark"
>   --num-executors 40 --executor-memory 2g CD.py

However my code runs very slow, it takes almost 1 hour to parse 8.2 GB of data.
Then i tried to change the configuration in my **YARN**. I changed following properties.

```
yarn.scheduler.increment-allocation-mb = 2 GiB

yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb = 2 GiB

yarn.scheduler.increment-allocation-mb = 2 GiB

yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb = 2 GiB
```

After doing these changes still my spark is running very slow and taking more than 1 hour to parse 8.2 GB of files.

Answer (score 1):

could you please try with the below configuration

spark.executor.memory    5g

spark.executor.cores     5

spark.executor.instances   3

spark.driver.cores    2